# Get item and all related tags with one query

Tags: sql-server, subsonic

I have the following tables structure:

Item:

```
Id,         
Description
```

Tags:

```
Id,
TagName
```

ItemXrefTag

```
 Id,
 TagId,
 ItemId
```

What is the best way to read all the items related to some tag and all other tags, related to the items, to be able to display list of items and all the tags related to the item?

If it's not clear I`ll give the example:

Item, Tags:

```
 Code complete, book|programming|cool
 Reactoring, book|programming|refactoring|cool
 C# for dummies, book|dont like it| not cool
```

P.S. I'm using subsonic, but as it support getting data fro mthe query Im ok with the query that will let me get all the data. Sure I can perform join and iterate through multiple lines Ill get and make collection of items with collection of tags for each of it. Im just interested in the most efficient way to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for the `GROUP_CONCAT` function. Just tried it on my database with

```
SELECT o.orderno,
       GROUP_CONCAT(d.itemno ORDER BY d.itemno ASC SEPARATOR ', ') as items
FROM order o
LEFT JOIN order_detail d ON o.id = d.order_id
GROUP BY d.order_id
ORDER BY o.id ASC
```

returns a result of order numbers with a comma seperated list of ordered items:

```
orderno   | items
----------------------------------
201010001 | 100123, 100456, 100987
201010002 | 123456, 123457
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

But I suppose this is not ANSI SQL so it won't be available for SQL-Server ;-), but a quick search here at stackoverflow returned this question: [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005)

The corresponding command in sql server should be `CROSS APPLY`

Another good article about CROSS APPLY

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-cross-apply-in-sql-server-2005

For usage with subsonic you should use an `InlineQuery` (aka `CodingHorror`) to execute raw sql with subsonic.

Answer (score 0):

here's an example to join all the data.  unless you specify a format you want this is the best i can do.

```
declare @item table (IID int identity(1,1), Description varchar(max))
declare @tags table (TID int identity(1,1), TagName varchar(50))
declare @ItemXrefTag table (XID int identity(1,1), TID int, IID int)


insert into @item values ('Book A')
insert into @item values ('Book B')


insert into @tags values ('Awesome!')
insert into @tags values ('Suckage!')
insert into @tags values ('Mediocre')


insert into @ItemXrefTag values (1,1)
insert into @ItemXrefTag values (3,1)
insert into @ItemXrefTag values (2,2)








select *
from @ItemXrefTag a
    left outer join @tags b
        on a.TID=b.TID
    left outer join @item c
        on a.IID=c.IID
```

Comment: ok, this will join all the data. But I need the way to:
1). Get Item and all tags related to it.
2). Do not get additional requests to server or more data from the server, than I need. In your case I`ll have too much of the same items. If one item has 10 tags I`ll have 10 rows of the same item data ...

Comment: So, what you're saying is is you need an sp to pass the Item ID, get all of the tags, and combine all of the tags into a single record?